# Getting error - The selected cells are read-only

Tags: wss-3.0, list

hi
I am trying to copy data from one list to another list using Datasheet view and I am getting above error. How to solve it? I use WSS 3.0

-saumil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also seen this on a links list where the first column has the little link icon. If that's the case copy and paste only the column containing the links themselves, as opposed to the whole grid.

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying to drag values from a look up columns?  I have seen this happen before when you are attempting to copy values from a column that is a look up to values in another list.

Comment: i am doing a simple - copy-paste .. from one list to another...

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question and has already been answered, but both the answers here led me in the right direction. Since my reputation isn't good enough to comment on their answers I simply decided to write out my own answer that details what caused this same problem for me, and how I resolved it.

I also got the 'The Selected Cells are Read Only' error. The problem columns were added columns from a lookup column. For instance, when we created a lookup column, we checked 'Add a column to show each of these additional fields' on a few of them. Those columns then got added to a view that we were attempting to use in datasheet mode. Whenever they would try to copy/paste an entire row, the error would show up.

My original fix was to just create another view that didn't include those additional columns. Once those columns were dropped, they had no problems copying and pasting an entire row. After, they realized they didn't even need to see those columns because they can view them by clicking on the main column that populates them anyways, so we modfied the original view as well, and dropped those columns off. So thanks for the above answers as they led me in the right direction in that it was the lookup columns causing the issue.